# How to fetch data from two table that have one to many relationship in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, go, inner-join

I have two struct:

```
type User struct {
    Id uint32
    First string
    Last string
    Adds []Address
}

type Address struct {
    Id uint32
    Location string
}
```

And i have two table:

```
create table user (
    Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    First VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    Last VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

create table address (
    Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Location VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES user (Id),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

**"address"** table has **one to many** relationship with **"user"** table.
so how can i fetch data from these two table with **inner join** and save it in **"user" struct instance**?

**Note**: Without **gorm** or other **orm** library?

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Nothing???

Comment: I tried something like answer from @Tim Cooper but i want to use join in my query string instead of two separate query string?

Comment: Then post your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single query and a JOIN:

```
func GetUser(db *sql.DB, id int) (*User, error) {    
    rows, err := db.Query(`
        SELECT
            User.Id AS UserId,
            User.First AS UserFirst,
            User.Last AS UserLast,
            Location.Id AS LocationId,
            Location.Location AS LocationLocation
        FROM User
        LEFT JOIN Location ON
            User.Id = Location.UserId
        WHERE User.Id = ?
    `, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var u *User
    for rows.Next() {
        if u == nil {
            u = new(User)
        }
        var locationID sql.NullInt64
        var location sql.NullString
        err := rows.Scan(
            &u.Id,
            &u.First,
            &u.Last,
            &locationID,
            &location,
        )
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if locationID.Valid && location.Valid {
            u.Adds = append(u.Adds, Address{
                Id:       uint32(locationID.Int64),
                Location: location.String,
            })
        }
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

Alternatively, you can use two queries, which is cleaner in my opinion:

```
func GetUser(db *sql.DB, id int) (*User, error) {
    u := new(User)
    err := db.QueryRow(`
        SELECT
            Id,
            First,
            Last
        FROM
            user
        WHERE Id = ?   
    `, id).Scan(
        &u.Id,
        &u.First,
        &u.Last,
    )
    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            return nil, nil
        }
        return nil, err
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(`
        SELECT
            Id,
            Location
        FROM
            addresses
        WHERE UserId = ?
    `, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var address Address
        err := rows.Scan(
            &address.Id,
            &address.Location,
        )
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        u.Adds = append(u.Adds, address)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use join in query string instead of two separate query string?

Comment: @samadadi: Why is there a requirement to use a JOIN? The situation doesn't warrant it.

Comment: What do you mean by "The situation doesn't warrant it."?

Comment: @samadadi: I've updated my answer with a solution that uses a single query and a JOIN.

Comment: cool man. I have one more question. which has performance preference?